# Argument 1 passed to SessionGuard::login() must be an instance of Auth\Authenticatable in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2.

I added a new field to the `users` table called `username` and I included it in the view and `AuthController.php`

I am also doing a check to see if the user is going to use a reserved slug for his username, if yes, I throw an error, if the username is good, I save in the database.

I am checking against 2 reserved slugs `banner` and `image` - that's all I have reserved.

If I remove the check, the data gets saved in the database normally, including the reserved slugs. So I must do the check.

However, when I apply the check, I get this error

> ErrorException in SessionGuard.php line 439:
>
> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\socialnet\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php on line 63 and defined

This is my code in `AuthController` after I've modified it

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        'username' => 'required|alpha_num|unique:users,username',
    ]);
}

protected function create(array $data)
{
    $check = $this->slugCheck($data['username']);

    if($check['status'] == 'nok') {
        return 'this username is a reserved name';
    } else {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'username' => $data['username'],
        ]);
    }
}

public function slugCheck($slug){

    $slug = strtolower($slug);

    // is the slug in the banned words list
    //
    if(array_search($slug, array('','banner','image'))){
        return array('status' => 'nok', 'message' => 'This slug is on a list of reserved names');
    }

    $user = User::where('username', '=', $slug)->first();

    if($user){
        return array('status' => 'nok', 'message' => 'This slug is already taken');
    } else {
        return array('status' => 'ok', 'message' => 'Slug is unique');
    }

}
```

If I `dd($check)` after declaring the `$check` variable and choosing a reserved name, I get the correct response.

```
array:2 [▼
  "status" => "nok"
  "message" => "This slug is on a list of reserved names"
]
```

Comment: make sure you added username to User.php $fillable array.

Comment: What does your User model looks like?

Comment: @ClearBoth It's already there.
@manniL it's a simple model with `$fillable` and `$hidden`

Comment: that error is straight forward. when $check['status'] == 'nok' is true it will not return instance of the class. instead it will return string. you can solve this by adding your check in some middleware

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because you're returning a string and the class is expecting an instance of Authenticatable.

Moving your validation in a middleware is your option. Create a middleware that checks if the username  is a 'Slug' and only procede to create()  method when validation passes otherwise, return the string: 'The username is a reserved name'

Now you can clean up the AuthController by removing the slugCheck method and you can always certain that whenever create()  method was called, that username isn't Slug.

You can check the laravel documentation

Comment: I tried this, however adding the middleware to the RegisterController.php's constructor did not work. I had to add my middleware to the route ```Route::post('register', [RegisterController::class, 'register'])->middleware('whitelisted.register');``` for it to do what I wanted.