# Laravel auth - Two step registeration

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-authentication

I do not know English much.
I want to register a member with 2 steps but I get an error

I am getting error different from type 1
Error : **SessionGuard::login() must be an instance of**

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
     if ($data['type'] == 0){
      $user = User::create([
                'type' => 0,
                'name' => $data['name'],
                'gender' => $data['gender'],
                'email' => $data['email'],
                'phone' => $data['phone'],
                'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
      ]);
      $user->assignRole('User');
      return $user;
      } else {
        // Redirect to 2 step form.
      }
}
```

Step 2 Form:

```
<form>
  ... bla bla bla
</form>
```

Step 2 create function :

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
$user = User::create([
                'type' => 1,
                'name' => $data['name'],
                'gender' => $data['gender'],
                'email' => $data['email'],
                'phone' => $data['phone'],
                'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
      ]);
}
```

Help me please...

Comment: Add the entire error, and if you're sure it fails there your User model.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38404448/argument-1-passed-to-sessionguardlogin-must-be-an-instance-of-auth-authentic